# "brics_actuator" for ROS Kinetic

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I am trying to use a package [Youbot Simulation](https://github.com/svenschneider/youbot-manipulation). The problem is that it asks me for `brics_actuator`. I have tried using this [link](http://wiki.ros.org/cob_common) and [this link](https://github.com/wnowak/brics_actuator-release).

I shall be very thankful to you if someone could give me some clue to help me resolve this.

I am using ROS Kinetic.

Thank You in advanced.

=========== Edit 1 ==============

After using [this link](https://github.com/wnowak/brics_actuator), I got the following error,

```
    In file included from /opt/ros/kinetic/include/moveit/macros/class_forward.h:40:0,
                 from /opt/ros/kinetic/include/moveit/kinematics_base/kinematics_base.h:42,
                 from /home/khan/catkin_ws/src/youbot-manipulation/youbot_arm_kinematics_moveit/ros/include/youbot_arm_kinematics_moveit/youbot_arm_kinematics_moveit.h:6,
                 from /home/khan/catkin_ws/src/youbot-manipulation/youbot_arm_kinematics_moveit/ros/src/youbot_arm_kinematics_moveit.cpp:1:
/opt/ros/kinetic/include/moveit/macros/declare_ptr.h:52:16: error: ‘shared_ptr’ in namespace ‘std’ does not name a template type
   typedef std::shared_ptr<Type> Name##Ptr;                                                                             \
                ^
/opt/ros/kinetic/include/moveit/macros/class_forward.h:51:3: note: in expansion of macro ‘MOVEIT_DECLARE_PTR’
   MOVEIT_DECLARE_PTR(C, C);
   ^
/opt/ros/kinetic/include/moveit/kinematics_base/kinematics_base.h:137:1: note: in expansion of macro ‘MOVEIT_CLASS_FORWARD’
 MOVEIT_CLASS_FORWARD(KinematicsBase);
 ^
/opt/ros/kinetic/include/moveit/macros/declare_ptr.h:53:16: error: ‘shared_ptr’ in namespace ‘std’ does not name a template type
   typedef std::shared_ptr<const Type> Name##ConstPtr;
                ^
/opt/ros/kinetic/include/moveit/macros/class_forward.h:51:3: note: in expansion of macro ‘MOVEIT_DECLARE_PTR’
   MOVEIT_DECLARE_PTR(C, C);
   ^
/opt/ros/kinetic/include/moveit/kinematics_base/kinematics_base.h:137:1: note: in expansion of macro ‘MOVEIT_CLASS_FORWARD’
 MOVEIT_CLASS_FORWARD(KinematicsBase);
 ^
youbot-manipulation/youbot_arm_kinematics_moveit/CMakeFiles/youbot_arm_kinematics_moveit.dir/build.make:62: recipe for target 'youbot-manipulation/youbot_arm_kinematics_moveit/CMakeFiles/youbot_arm_kinematics_moveit.dir/ros/src/youbot_arm_kinematics_moveit.cpp.o' failed
```

I believe that I have to enable C++11. Could you please tell me how did you do it? I think the error which I was receiving previously has been removed.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/272290/%22brics_actuator%22-for-ros-kinetic/) by [Abdul Mannan](https://answers.ros.org/users/25557/abdul-mannan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 167 on 2017-10-04

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You likely just need to clone [this repo](https://github.com/wnowak/brics_actuator) into your workspace's `src` directory and then run `catkin_make` to properly build the messages required by your package.

---

Originally posted by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) with karma: 9031 on 2017-10-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Abdul Mannan](https://answers.ros.org/users/25557/abdul-mannan/) on 2017-10-05**:
I have tried but it does not work.

**Comment by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) on 2017-10-05**:
Could you possibly edit your question to explain how or why it does not work?

**Comment by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) on 2017-10-05**:
I just tested and I was able to compile a workspace that contained only the `youbot_simulation` package you linked and the `brics_actuator` package I linked on Kinetic. The only change I needed to make was enabling C++11 for the `youbot_arm_kinematics_moveit` package.

**Comment by [Abdul Mannan](https://answers.ros.org/users/25557/abdul-mannan/) on 2017-10-05**:
I believe that I have to enable C++11. Could you please tell me how did you do it? I think the error which I was receiving previously has been removed.

**Comment by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) on 2017-10-06**:
This is probably not the best CMake-y way to do this, but I just added `SET(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")` to the `CMakeLists.txt` in the `youbot_arm_kinematics_moveit` directory.